# Python mechanize - set_proxies method ignores proxy and does nothing

Tags: python, proxy, mechanize

I am trying to set an http proxy when creating a mechanize broswer instance but it doesn't seem to be working at all or throwing any kind of errors.

```
from mechanize import Browser
br = Browser()
ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/1    8.0 (compatible;)'
br.addheaders = [('User-Agent', ua), ('Accept', '*/*')]
br.set_proxies({'http':'116.226.11.254:8118'})
br.open("https://xxx.xxx")
```

This code still opens the url with local ip and doesn't use the proxy at all. If proxy were unreachable then it should have thrown such error but its not happening. I tried to put in some invalid ip for proxy like

```
br.set_proxies({'http':'116.22as6.11.25as4:8118'})
```

but this code doesnt throw any error too!!
Is is possible that some other inbuild python code is re-writing proxy?
I am using python 2.7.10 inside a virtual environment with latest mechanize, and trying to open an https address with this code

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732160/proxy-seems-to-be-ignored-by-mechanize) but it still ignores proxy

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are setting proxy just for the 'http' protocol, but call 'https' in br.open.

Try replacing the protocol to 'https' in the br.set_proxies.

Comment: http is for proxy type in set proxies. Proxy i am using is Http and not https.

Answer (score 0):

after hours of researching I have realised that this function of mechanize is useless, so I found another method to make this work with mechanize requests:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import mechanize
import socks
import socket

# This will be printing your real ip
print mechanize.Browser().open("https://api.ipify.org/?format=raw").read()
ip = "0.0.0.0"
port = 1234
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, ip, port)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [("User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0")]
# Then with your proxy:
print br.open("https://api.ipify.org/?format=raw").read()
# Will be printing the ip from the proxy
```

And then this REALLY works for me. I hope this work for you!

Comment: If you want help, better  describe why your code will help. Because you have only one diff in **Accept** header.

Answer (score 0):

```
br.set_handled_schemes(['https', 'http'])
```

Did it for me.